# Элемент во всю длину

Tags: html, css

Связался с такой проблемой при верстке. Слева стоит небольшой слайдер, а справа должно стоять меню и оно (его фон) должно растягиваться в зависимости от разрешения экрана. Пробовал ставить `width: 100%`, но оно сразу перескакивает на другую строчку.

Comment: Попробуйте выставить слайдеру float: left.

Comment: С самого начала поставил.

Comment: Меню должно растягиваться или его фон? Можно посмотреть верстку?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="wrapper" style="background:url(image.jpg) right center repeat-x;">
  <div class="slider" style="float:left"></div>
  <div class="menu" style="float:right"></div>
  <div class="clear" style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

ставите фон на div.wrapper, слайдер слева, меню справа

Comment: Мне нужно, так сказать, несколько этажей меню.

Comment: так в чём проблема? div.menu может выступать как контейнер для менюшек

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="slaider"></div>
     <div class="menu"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
.slaider {
   float: left;
   width: 400px; /* ширина слайдера */
}

.menu { 
   position: relative;
   margin-left: 410px; /* ширина слайдера + отступ если нужно (минимум - ширина слайдера)  */
}
```

Так меню обязано растянуться на всю оставшуюся ширину экрана.

Comment: <a href="http://tsya.ru">http://tsya.ru</a>

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="slaider"></div>
     <div class="menu"></div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

.clear{clear: both; font-size: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;}
```

Это поможет избежать некоторых проблем с элементами ниже float, но вариант с float+margin-left сам по себе неправильный.

Answer (score 0):

Абсолютное позиционирование тебе о чём-нибудь говорит?